# Swift 3, how to take either Set or Array as argument. Generics, overload?

Tags: arrays, generics, swift3, set, overloading

I have a func/method that takes an array of strings and returns a concatenated string.

I'd like to be able to take either an array or set of strings. I was able to do it this way by overloading the init method of a struct:

```
struct SetOrArr {

    var stringSet = Set<String>()
    var stringArr = [String]()

    init(_ stringSet: Set<String>) {
        self.stringSet = stringSet
    }

    init(_ stringArr: [String]) {
        self.stringArr = stringArr
    }
}
```

I looked thru the generics docs and see I can accept a set or array with any type, but don't see a way to accept either set/array. Is that possible? Or is there a better way to execute this?

TIA

Comment: You can accept a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a method, [`Sequence.joined(seperator:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/protocol/Sequence/#comment-func-iterator-element-string-joined_) that does this. Since `Set` and `Array` both conform to `Sequence`, they inherit this default method.

Here is what an implementation of it might look like:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {
    func myJoined(seperator: String) -> String {
        var string = ""

        var iterator = this.makeIterator()

        if let first = iterator.next() {
            string += first
        }

        while let element = iterator.next() {
            string += seperator + element
        }

        return string
    }
}

let array = (0...10).map(String.init)
let joinedArray = array.myJoined(seperator: ", ")

let set = Set(array)
let joinedSet = set.myJoined(seperator: ", ")


print("Array: [\(joinedArray)]") // Array: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print("Set: {\(joinedSet)}")     // Set: {7, 8, 4, 1, 3, 6, 9, 10, 0, 2, 5}
```

Comment: Think you forgot to add declaration for 'iterator' in code above. Should be 'var iterator = makeIterator()' ??

Comment: @bigswifty Yeeep. Made a mistake in copying

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for pointing me in this direction Alexander, hadn't gotten to Extensions yet.

I had been using Sequence.joined(), but wanted to do both Sets & Arrays. Also, my func needed to not only separate but quote out the string (for SQL statements).

Here's what I came up with:

```
    extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {
    func getQuotedString(seperator: String, quote: String) -> String {

        var string = ""
        var iterator = makeIterator()

        if let first = iterator.next() {
            string += quote + first + quote + seperator
        }

        while let element = iterator.next() {
            string += quote + element + quote + seperator
        }

        string = String(string.characters.dropLast(seperator.characters.count))

        return string
    }
}
```

Works great, thanks again.